# Bindings not working on cloned UIElement from Code-Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a UIBlockContainer that serves as a template for presenting a payslip.
I provided it an x:Name to be able to access it on code-behind and being able to clone it. My problem is that the cloned object's binding doesn't seem to work even though I've provided the DataContext of the UIBlockContainer.

I've tried using the relative source binding and setting the ancestortype=UIBlockContainer but it doesn't work still.

It only works when I tried manually setting their respective values by using this:

```
private void AssignPayslipValues(BlockUIContainer payslipContainer, View_Models.PayslipViewModel.Payslip payslip)
        {
            ((Run)payslipContainer.FindName("FullName")).Text = payslip.PayrollDetail.Employee.FullName;
            ((Run)payslipContainer.FindName("StartDate")).Text = payslip.PayrollDetail.Payroll.StartDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            ((Run)payslipContainer.FindName("EndDate")).Text = payslip.PayrollDetail.Payroll.EndDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        }
```

Here's an example part of the BlockUIContainer that uses Binding the FullName, StartDate, and EndDate is empty:

```
 <BlockUIContainer x:Name="blockUI_playslip" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                    <Grid>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,10">
                            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30">PAYSLIP</Label>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock>
                                    <Run>NAME:</Run>
                                    <Run Name="FullName" Text="{Binding PayrollDetail.Employee.FullName}" />
                                </TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Run>Payroll Period:</Run>
                                    <Run Name="StartDate" Text="{Binding PayrollDetail.Payroll.StartDate}" />
                                    <Run>-</Run>
                                    <Run Name="EndDate" Text="{Binding PayrollDetail.Payroll.EndDate}" />
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
...
</BlockUIContainer>
```

And here's the code for cloning and adding the object as child to a parent UIElement.

```
private void populateFlowDocuments()    
        {
            foreach (var payslip in VM.Payslips)
            {
                var clonedPayslipUI = ClonePayslip(blockUI_playslip);
                clonedPayslipUI.DataContext = payslip;
                fd_Payslip.Blocks.Add(clonedPayslipUI);
            }
        }
        private BlockUIContainer ClonePayslip(BlockUIContainer block)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, new XmlWriterSettings
            {
                Indent = true,
                ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment,
                OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
                NamespaceHandling = NamespaceHandling.OmitDuplicates,
            });
            var mgr = new XamlDesignerSerializationManager(writer);

            // HERE BE MAGIC!!!
            mgr.XamlWriterMode = XamlWriterMode.Expression;
            // THERE WERE MAGIC!!!

            XamlWriter.Save(block, mgr); 

            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
            BlockUIContainer newBlock = (BlockUIContainer)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
            return newBlock;
        }
```

Comment: You should include a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, if you want someone to debug the code for you. That said, "cloning" in WPF doesn't make any sense. Any time you have the urge to "clone" a UI object, it surely means what you should be doing instead is declaring a data template that applies for a specific view model type, then use that view model type in any content control where you want that template to show up.

Comment: I want to be able to populate a flow document with a collection of items with each item being represented by the BlockUIContainer so that the pagination will work properly however I can't put an Itemscontrol element that's why I'm doing it in code-behind instead to be able to copy the template of the BlockUIContainer and then put it inside the flow document.